# Pobres "cabeceras" HTTP, tan ignoradas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Sobre la etiqueta [cabeceras-http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabeceras-http), creo que no es tan importante (14 preguntas actualmente), pero me gusta poder usarla para filtrar preguntas.

Será un tema de localismo, pero yo no uso el término "***cabecera***" jamás:
uso "***header***" o "***encabezado***"... Pero vi que "cabecera" se usa en toda la web ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Cabeceras_HTTP)), -aunque tengo a algunos de mi lado ([w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset.es), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Los_encabezados_HTTP_de_respuesta), [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_encabezado_HTTP)).

Además, buscando [`header http -[cabeceras-http] is:q`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=header+http+-%5Bcabeceras-http%5D+is%3Aq) hay varias preguntas (527 actualmente). Posiblemente varias de estas hubiesen sido etiquetadas como [cabeceras-http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabeceras-http) si el autor hubiese encontrado la etiqueta.

Tengo la impresión de que es un nombre de etiqueta difícil de encontrar, a veces tengo que hacer un esfuerzo para recordar cuál era la palabra usada. Entonces, propongo crear 2 nuevas etiquetas que serían sinónimos de esta, con la intención de que sea más sencillo encontrarla, y que sirva para organizar mejor al sitio, pudiendo usarlas para filtrar:

1. [cabeceras-http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabeceras-http) ← [encabezados-http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encabezados-http)
2. [cabeceras-http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabeceras-http) ← [http-headers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-headers)

Creo que podría ser útil crearlas.

Comment: Yo he usado `cabecera` o `header`, pero `encabezado` no lo había oído nunca para referirse al término. Me parece bien que estén las distintas variantes si las usa la gente. Otra etiqueta útil podría ser `bucles`, ya que solo está `loops`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de usar en la búsqueda `-[cabeceras-http] `?

Comment: @Flxtr era para mostrar que había muchas preguntas que hablan de headers HTTP pero que **no están etiquetadas** como [tag:cabeceras-http]... Obviamente en muchas no correspondería, pero en varias creo que sí. Fue un enlace para facilitar que vean sobre qué tipo de preguntas estoy hablando.

Comment: Concuerdo con usar http-headers. Por otro lado he visto muy poco encabezados-http y nunca lo he usado. Quizás 'encabezados' también sea un localismo de ciertas zonas hispanohablantes. Lo mejor sería sacar una estadística por cantidad de búsquedas.

Comment: @Deoxyseia seguramente es un localismo.No obstante, no creo que tenga mucha importancia que se cree como sinónimo: no interfiere con ninguna otra etiqueta, no altera en absoluto a la etiqueta actual, sólo amplía las posibilidades de encontrarla en una búsqueda... De todas formas, los términos utilizados en las búsquedas entiendo que son privados, por lo que no tendríamos acceso a ese dato.